# SSIS Lookup Suggestion

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a task to Generate a Derived Column (RestrictionID) from a table and add it to a source table if 6 columns on both tables match. The 6 columns include (Country, Department, Account .etc) I decided to go with the SSIS Lookup and generate the Derived column when there's a match. This ID also has a time and amount Limit. Once all the records have ID's, I'm supposed to calculate a running total based on the ID to enforce the limits which is the easy part.

The only problem is this Lookup table changes almost daily and any or all of the 6 columns can have NULLS. Even the completely null rows have an Id. Nulls mean the Restriction is open. eg. If the Country column on one record on the lookup table is null, then the ID of that record can be assigned to records with any country on the source. If one row on the lookup has all null columns, then this is completely open and all records on the source qualify for that ID. The Source table doesn't have NULLS.

Please assist if possible

Thanks

Comment: Hm... sounds a bit strange. My first approach would be to create a view of the lookup table, which includes all valid combinations and with this includes no NULL values. Then I would configure the Lookup in SSIS against this view instead of the table.

Comment: It is not a best practice to use null columns for look up, but if you can eliminate rows with null values and do a look up on ID column that would get required results, Can you possibly add source table and look up table

Comment: As always I recommend doing... whatever you're doing... in a stored proc

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Right now there is at least one null column on all the rows in the lookup table.

Comment: Maybe to give more context, the Lookup table is a Grant table and the Source table is Journal entry table. The Goal is to tie each Journal entry to a Grant based on 6 columns. (Country, Department, BusinessUnit, Account, BoardLine and BVALevel). On the Lookup table, all these columns allow NULLS but this is also relevant because a grant with NULL department column means ALL departments qualify for the Grant.

Comment: I don't understand your business rules. Sample data always helps. Is there always a one to one match? Can a record in grant match 0 records in Journal? 1 record? many records? and vice versa. Is it a multi-pass operation to decide which grant matches which journal?

Answer (score 0):

If NULL means any and ignore column in lookup then add this to your where:

use a stored proc and pass your values in and return:

```
select lookup.ID
from lookup
where @Country = isnull(lookup.Country,@Country) //If lookup inull then it refers to itself creating a 1=1 scenario
  and @Department = isnull(lookup.Department,@Department)
  and ...
```